# Find the area of the domain bounded by $ y^2-x^2+x^4=0$

Tags: calculus, integration

We have an example in our course material where we need to find the area of the domain bounded by $ y^2-x^2+x^4=0$.

The solution goes as following:

$y^2-x^2+x^4=0 \Rightarrow y=\pm x\sqrt{1-x^2}$

By the graph of the function we can conclude
$ A=4\int_0^1 x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx$. By choosing substitutes $ t=1-x^2 $ and $ dt=-2xdx $ we get 
$$A=4\int_0^1 x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=4\int_1^0 \sqrt{t}(-\frac{dt}{2})=-2\int_1^0 \sqrt{t} dt=2\int_0^1\sqrt{t} dt=\frac{4}{3}. $$

In this particular problem I'm not sure how we switched the integral from $0$ to $1$, to $1$ to $0$ on

$$4\int_0^1 x\sqrt{1-x^2}dx=4\int_1^0 \sqrt{t}(-\frac{dt}{2}).$$

What is the integration rule that says we need change to the domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integration rule I believe you are looking for is
$\int_a^bf(g(x))g'(x)dx=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(u)du$ where $u=g(x)$. So in your case, when you let $t=t(x) = 1-x^2$ with $0\leq x \leq 1$ we get that $t = 0$ when $x=1$, i.e., $t(1)=0$, and similarly, $t(0)=1$, which provides the limits of integration.